# Ajuda com um jogo simples

Tags: python, jogos, pygame

Bom, estou tentando fazer uma "bola" seguir o retângulo do jogar, porém não parece estar acontecendo isso, pois a "bola" meio que borra a tela quando eu movo o jogador. Já procurei pela solução do problema e não achei nada.

Previamente eu tinha o mesmo problema só que só para desenhar um retângulo que se mexe e o problema era que eu estava usando window.fill(color) depois de desenhar o retângulo. Desta vez não é o caso, mesmo mudando de local a função não acontece nada.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

isRunning = True

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface((60, 30))
        self.image.fill((200, 255, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 30

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0

        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -5

        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 5

        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if self.rect.right + self.speedx > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH

        if self.rect.left + self.speedx < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        ball = Ball(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        for i in all_sprites:
            print(i)
        all_sprites.add(ball)

    def shoot(self):
        ball = Ball(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(ball)
        balls.add(ball)

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((100, 150, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -3

    def update(self):
        pass
        #self.rect.y += self.speedy

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

while isRunning:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    window.fill((0, 0, 30))

    all_sprites.update()

    all_sprites.draw(window)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O principal problema do seu código é que você cria um novo objeto `Ball` **a cada novo quadro do jogo**. Além de causar o efeito indesejado, você está consumindo absurdamente a memória do seu jogo. O correto é criar esse objeto apenas a cada chamada do método `shoot` da sua classe do jogador, e garantir que a bola seja eliminada assim que ela saia dos limites da tela - ou colida com alguma outra coisa, caso ela seja uma bala ("*bullet*") e não uma bola ("*ball*"). :)

O outro problema (o que motivou a pergunta) é que você não move a bola. Como você está usando uma abordagem orientada a objetos, esse código de mover deve ser realizado na própria classe da bola. Basta fazer com que o centro da bola seja igual ao centro do jogador. Como o seu jogador está numa variável global, isso é trivial de fazer. Mas o ideal era adicionar o jogador a um atributo da classe bola (no construtor, ou em um método adicional do tipo `setParent`).

Eis uma versão do código com essas correções:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

isRunning = True

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface((60, 30))
        self.image.fill((200, 255, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 30

        self.balls = []

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0

        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -5

        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 5

        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if self.rect.right + self.speedx > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH

        if self.rect.left + self.speedx < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        #ball = Ball(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        #for i in all_sprites:
        #    print(i)
        #all_sprites.add(ball)

    def shoot(self):
        ball = Ball(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(ball)

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((100, 150, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = -3

        self.player = None

    def update(self):
        # Move a bola para cima, na velocidade configurada
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        # Move a bola para a posicao central (no eixo X) do player
        self.rect.centerx = player.rect.centerx

        # Verifica se a bola ja saiu da tela
        if self.rect.centery <= 0:
            all_sprites.remove(self)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

while isRunning:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            isRunning = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    window.fill((0, 0, 30))

    all_sprites.update()
    sys.stdout.write('\rTotal de sprites em jogo: {:5d}'.format(len(all_sprites)))

    all_sprites.draw(window)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

E o resultado do "jogo" funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P.S.: repare que eu imprimi a "contagem" de *sprites* em jogo usando o `\r` na string e o `sys.stdout.write` apenas para ele imprimir sempre na mesma posição (e não ficar imprimindo uma linha atrás da outra, como o seu código fazia antes). Essa contagem garante que nessa versão do código você não está ficando com nenhum "vazamento de memória" (com *sprites* perdidas não deletadas).

Comment: Então, obrigado pela resposta, mas não era bem isso que eu queria no resultado final.

Eu fiz a mesma pergunta no Stack Overflow gringo e lá me explicaram que eu estava criando a instância e adicionando várias vezes no grupo e tal, pois então, eu estava confundindo a lógica da função " pygame.draw.rect(Surface, Color, (x, y, w, h))", que pode ser usada no looping e mesmo assim vai se auto excluir, porém com o grupo isso tem que ser manualmente feito (por código).

Novamente, agradeço pelo tempo que você tomou para me explicar.

Vou deixar o link do programa do outro Stack Overflow abaixo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834370/pygame-logic-issue/40838269?noredirect=1#comment68924361_40838269

O código está na parte que ele editou, ou seja, o código mais para baixo.

Comment: A, e mais uma coisa, meu objetivo de jogo não é fazer um shooter e sim um Breakout ou Brick Breaker, eu havia implementado esse código "Shoot" só para testes.

Comment: Por nada. Mas, enfim, como você percebeu, fica difícil saber o que você precisa se você não explica direitinho né? E, sim, eu fui levado a crer que não era uma bola por causa do método `shoot`. :) Boa sorte!